# Einstein says that this equation is true, but WolframAlpha says it's not always true. Who is right?

Tags: special-relativity

Einstein says
$$\cos\mathrm{i}x=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\left(\mathrm{i}\tan\mathrm{i}x\right)^2}},$$
but WolframAlpha says that [this isn't true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20cos%20%28ix%29%20%3D%201%2Fsqrt%281-%28itan%28ix%29%29%5E2%29%3F) for $x=\pm2$ and $x=\pm9/5$. What's happening?

From page 34 of The Meaning of Relativity:

$$v=\mathrm{i}\tan\mathrm{i}\theta,\quad\mathrm{i}\sin\mathrm{i}\theta=\dfrac{v}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\quad\text{and}\quad \cos\mathrm{i}\theta=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-v^2}}.$$

Otherwise, the functions do appear to be identical.

Comment: Without working thru the example I would take it that Wolfram is considering points where the denominator goes to zero.  This is mathematically possible but maybe not physically possible.

Comment: compare your query with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+cos+%28ix%29sqrt%281-%28itan%28ix%29%29%5E2%29+%3D+1 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos+%28ix%29sqrt%281-%28itan%28ix%29%29%5E2%29+

Comment: On general formatting, note that plus/minus is \pm and it generally looks nicer to use \sqrt{ ... }.

Comment: *Mathematica* says that that equality is true, symbolically. At $x=2$ both sides are numerically equal to 3.7622. I would ignore what Wolfram Alpha is saying.

Comment: I wonder why Einstein didn’t like the hyperbolic functions cosh and tanh. All those $i$’s are awful.

Comment: WolframAlpha is math.  Physics is NOT math.  I would tend to believe Einstein.

Comment: There is a branch cut for the function on the right hand side in the complex plane due to the square root. I bet that wolfram alpha has some default prescription for handling the branch cut that caused it to make a silly choice when answering your question in the case where it does not assume $x$ is real. On the other hand, the box "assuming $x$ is real" (a) is the special case you are interested in so you should use this, and (b) I bet wolfram alpha makes a different choice for the branch cut so it doesn't hit the real axis in this case.

Comment: Please provide the reference where Einstein used this.

Comment: @robphy https://www.gutenberg.org/files/36276/36276-pdf.pdf page 35

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Einstein is right assuming real x. $$\cos (ix) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(i\tan(ix))^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(ix)}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\cos(ix)}}~.$$

As $\cos(ix)\gt 0$ this is an identity for all real x.